# how to use "in" clause of a sql in mysql++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

I have some data and I want to get the result at one time by using in clause from mysql db;
For example, I have some numbers like 97,87,73,100. I can use the sql like `select * from stock where num in (97,87,73,100)` to get a result set.

but how can I use it in `mysql++` to get all rows?
the `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult` only return the first row in my program.

Many Thanks.

Comment: using mysql++ in my program.  mysqlpp::Query query = con.query("select * from stock where num in (%0q)");

Comment: I found a way that the store_if could makes it work. but the store_if uses UseQueryResult  to get all the data and process it in the program. but I do not think it is a better way. It is better to filter the data I want to get in the 'in' clause in the mysql db, then transfer the useful data to my program.

Comment: con.query("select * from stock where num in (%0q)"). My mistake. the query string should not take the 'q' in the template query.